# Can anybody suggest jmeter script recording alternatives other than blazemeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

Can anybody suggest jmeter script recording alternatives other than blazemeter?
Blazemeter is not providing necessary data in the recorded script.

Comment: You should Definitely take a look at this **ultimate guide** reviewing most [Open-Source Load Testing tools](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/11/21/open-source-load-testing-tools/) available on the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [SmartMeter's](https://www.smartmeter.io/features) [Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-electron-script-recorder). SmartMeter is compatible with Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the most excellent test script creation utility with Octoperf?

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch Jmeter, then there are tools like LoadRunner and Tsung.

Answer (score 1):

First of all JMeter has its own built-in recording mechanism - [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), given you are trying to capture HTTP or HTTPS traffic it should catch all the requests properly. If it doesn't - raise a ticket in [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

Reference Material:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How To Use JMeter To Record Test Scenarios](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

---

Be aware that not everything can be recorded, i.e. if your application uses [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) or [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or relies on custom plugin content like [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) or [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) - most likely you won't be able to record the "uncommon" or proprietary protocols.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a record alternative, in the sense that it generates your Jmeter requests, but try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to analyze the traffic and base your script on that.

That is what I mostly use as I don't want to rely on recorders and it takes too much time to rewrite/de-cluther the recorded script in many cases anyway. Also a much better way to see and understand what is actually happening. And useful for different protocols, like Websockets. Just my 2cnts.